# MySQL - JOIN only if a row exists from the left table

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

Here is MySQL:

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.name,
        a.n,
        a.r,
        a.pot,
        a.ticket_price,
        a.starting_tickets,
        a.started,
        a.end,
        COUNT(b.id) tickets_bought 
FROM current_lotteries a
   JOIN lottery_tickets b ON b.lid=a.id
WHERE a.cid=1 
ORDER BY started DESC LIMIT 1
```

In the search, if there is no row from `a` but there are rows in `b` (i.e `COUNT(b.id)` is not `NULL`) then this query returns a row with `NULL` values for `a` fields and whatever the value of `COUNT(b.id)` as `tickets_bought`. How do I modify this query so it does not return a row (`num_rows = 0`) if there is no result in table `a`?

A Snap.

[image: query]

Comment: No, `tickets_bought` is an alias.

Comment: "this query returns a row with NULL values for `a` fields" I beg to differ, unless `a` can contain NULL values itself.

Comment: That is really the query you are using? The behavior you are describing is not that of an `INNER JOIN`, but rather that of a `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: I've checked the table structure, and under `NULL` each column has `no`. But when I run the above query it returns `NULL` for each of those fields.

Comment: Wait I think I see it - there's no GROUP BY and MySQL is being its usual confusing self with the aggregate.

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a5rwq982

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you. `GROUP BY(b.lid)` after the `WHERE` clause fixes it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absent a `GROUP BY` clause, MySQL (which permits this where it would be an error in other RDBMS) is applying the aggregate group over all rows in `b` when it should be grouping them.  Add `GROUP BY a.id`

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.name,
        a.n,
        a.r,
        a.pot,
        a.ticket_price,
        a.starting_tickets,
        a.started,
        a.end,
        COUNT(b.id) tickets_bought 
FROM current_lotteries a
   JOIN lottery_tickets b ON b.lid=a.id
WHERE a.cid=1 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY started DESC LIMIT 1
```

The above will work in MySQL but not elsewhere. A more portable version uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.name,
        a.n,
        a.r,
        a.pot,
        a.ticket_price,
        a.starting_tickets,
        a.started,
        a.end,
        b.tickets_bought
FROM current_lotteries a
        /* More portable to join against a subquery which returns the count per group */
        JOIN (
            SELECT b.lid, COUNT(*) AS tickets_bought 
            FROM lottery_tickets 
            GROUP BY lid
        ) b ON a.id = b.lid
WHERE a.cid = 1
ORDER BY started DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I grouped by `b.lid` and it seems to work, what's the difference?

Comment: @KeirSimmons In that version, no difference since it is an inner join.  The second query I posted is more appropriate though because it does not depend on a weird MySQL behavior.

Comment: @KeirSimmons: Without `GROUP BY`, it counts **all** rows returned by your query. But it is apparent from the query that you want counts per `a.id`. That's why you need to specify *grouping* by that criterion, and that affects the result(s) of `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.n, a.r, a.pot, a.ticket_price, 
       a.starting_tickets, a.started, a.end, b.tickets_bought 
FROM current_lotteries a 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT b.lid, COUNT(*) AS tickets_bought 
            FROM lottery_tickets GROUP BY lid ) b ON a.id = b.lid 
WHERE a.cid = 1 
ORDER BY started DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```